# How best to allocate and use memory when program traverses and reports on file system details

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc

I have a program which reads all the file system file/dir names, size etc. and populate in a tree data structure. Once this is done, it will generate a report.

I want write my program to collect and then report this data using memory in the most efficient way and without exceeding my heap space.

I worry that if the file system has a lot of files and dirs., it will consume a lot of memory and might eventually run out (`malloc()` will start to fail).

Eventually this is genuine memory consumption, Is there any methods/techniques to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could employ the Flyweight Design Pattern for each folder node.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Instead of storing the full path for each item, you could have a bit array of pointers to partial paths (folder names). These could then be easily reconstructed if needed.

It also depends on what you need for your report. Do you need to hold all the information in memory during construction, or could you just accumulate some of the space count variables as you traverse the tree?

Comment: Also, the data can be stored on disk.

Comment: @swinefeaster I already taken care of this, I makes sure that even single bytes are not wasted and datas are not repeated. The file/dir names are not full path, it stores only its name.

Comment: So then how could you possibly run out of memory? Maybe you should upgrade your RAM :) Or perhaps you are leaking or misusing memory in your program.

Comment: @swinefeaster As I mentioned earlier this is genuine memory build up and there is no memory leak :). I like to know is there any method/technique to tackle such kind of issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) could help you (at least on Linux).

Comment: As I mentioned earlier this is genuine memory build up and there is no memory leak :). I like to know is there any method/technique to tackle such kind of issues?

Comment: If you are sure the memory is absolutely needed, there is no way to avoid it, unless you redesign and recode your application.

Comment: Thank Basile, that is what I want to know. In general, if we face this situation how to redesign?

Comment: I don't understand your detailed specification. You could work in two passes: first, collect the relevant file paths (e.g. in your file or database); second, process file paths in sequence.